# is there any function to act as a magnet trigger in google cardboard api

Tags: google-cardboard

I looked into the CardBoard SDK for Android but I have not found any function which can generate a magnet trigger. But I could find bluetooth devices which can act as a magnet trigger - it is likely using some API to able to do that. So Is it possible to write such app which can generate magnet trigger? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to write an [accessibility service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html) which receives the bluetooth events and generate a [TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html#TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED) event